# "upsertWithWhere" is running infinite times

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to update a field in database using upsertWithWhere and that's what is happening too but the code is running infinite times if I am putting break statement I am getting error "illegal break statement", I tried with process.exit(),but no luck

```
  CampaignDetail.observe("after save", function(ctx, cb) {
    console.log("inside save");
    let sourceConditionCampaignId = ctx.instance.sourceConditionCampaignId;
    if (sourceConditionCampaignId != null) {
      CampaignDetail.find({
        where: { id: sourceConditionCampaignId }
      })
        .then(campaign => {
          console.log("inside campaign");
          let campaignConditionJSONValue = campaign[0].campaignConditionJSON;
          let cmd = ctx.instance;
          cmd.campaignConditionJSON = campaignConditionJSONValue;
          return cmd;
        })
        .then(updateCampaign => {
          console.log(updateCampaign);
          console.log("inside update campaign");
          let campId = ctx.instance.id;
          CampaignDetail.upsertWithWhere({ id: campId }, updateCampaign);
          return updateCampaign;
        })
    } else {
      console.log("selected campaign doesnt have the json");
    }
    let response = "stored";
    cb(null, response);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is why `upsertWithWhere` calls hook of `'after save'` function again.
There are several other functions to call after save hook function, in that case you can see the same infinite loop.

> This hook is triggered by the following methods of PersistedModel:
>   find() findOne() findById() exists() count() create() upsert() (same
>   as updateOrCreate()) upsertWithWhere() findOrCreate()*
>   prototype.save() prototype.updateAttributes() replaceOrCreate()
>   prototype.replaceAttributes() / replaceById()

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#after-save